# SkypeHost.exe, Microsoft.Photos.exe, Video.UI.exe

Tags: windows, tasks

In TaskManager I see some strange apps running all time :

[image]

However, i dont use any ms-photos, nor video.ui ... why are they running or how to permanently close them?

Comment: You might have a live tile for photos on your start menu. That might be the reason it's running. I'm not sure about the rest. Did you try to kill the process and see whenever it respawns?

Comment: They are not actually running, they are suspended, all of those applications are installed by default by the way.  You can end the process, but suspended UWP applications (I assume you are running Windows 10), do not consume resources.  Those applications are suspended because something launched them, otherwise they wouldn't have launched then suspend themselfs.

Comment: Because I was just trying to give some context and deem it insufficient as an answer. Thanks for your encouragement though! I know that some people reported that Skype was automatically launching for them. You could check the startup part of the task manager and have a look whenever one of them is listed. What version and edition of Windows are you running? They might behave differently.

Comment: @T.Todua - Questions that receive an answer are not typically closed.  As for an answer, you never provided the information, required to answer your question

Comment: @Ramhound sry, in "close" i didn't mean to actually close the question. I mean "close the case:)" , which means, marking the accepting answer, and thus, this question will be no longer "waiting for answers". that's what I meant. So, wahtever you commented above, please post that as answer, it's enough for me.